# SQL Server : number of orders per date with day column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that pulls number of orders per date.

```
SELECT 
    name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), order_date, 120) AS order_date, 
    COUNT(1) AS orders    
FROM 
    orders AS od
WHERE 
    id = 73
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), order_date, 120), name 
ORDER BY 
    order_date, name
```

Below are the results I get when I run the query:

```
    name    order_date  orders
    --------------------------
    20pmam  2016-07-27  39
    20pmam  2016-07-28  30
    20pmam  2016-07-29  32
    20pmam  2016-07-31  468
    20pmam  2016-08-02  75
    20pmam  2016-07-05  30
```

I need my results to be like this, with a new column day

```
name    order_date  orders  day 
-------------------------------
20pmam  2016-07-27  39      1
20pmam  2016-07-28  30      2 // days between 2016-07-27 to 2016-07-28
20pmam  2016-07-29  32      3 // days between 2016-07-27 to 2016-07-29
20pmam  2016-07-31  468     5 // days between 2016-07-27 to 2016-07-31
20pmam  2016-08-02  75      7 // days between 2016-07-27 to 2016-08-02
20pmam  2016-08-05  30      10 // days between 2016-07-27 to 2016-08-05
```

The first/minimum order_date should be taken as day 1 ( in the above results 2016-07-27 is day 1) and should calculate others based on the first/minimum order_date.

Is this easily possible?

I don't have any idea how to get the desired result. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this `cross apply` to get the minimum date before each order_date and use it in `datediff`.

```
SELECT name,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), order_date, 120) AS order_date, Count(1)  [orders], 
1+coalesce(datediff(day,t.min_date,od.order_date),0) as [Day]
FROM orders AS od
cross apply (select min(od1.order_date) as min_date
             from orders od1 
             where od.id=od1.id and od.name=od1.name and od1.order_date<od.order_date) t
WHERE id = 73
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), order_date, 120),name,datediff(day,t.min_date,od.order_date)
ORDER BY order_date,name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My actual query is little complicated but I got an idea how to get the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
SELECT name,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), order_date, 120) AS order_date, 
       Count(1) AS orders,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, first_order_date, order_date) + 1
FROM orders AS od 
JOIN (SELECT min(order_date) AS first_order_date
        FROM orders) as fod ON 1 = 1
WHERE id = 73
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), order_date, 120),
         name,
         DATEDIFF(DAY, first_order_date, order_date) + 1
ORDER BY order_date, 
         name
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My actual query is little complicated but I got an idea how to get the desired results.

Comment: FYI, an `INNER JOIN` on `1=1` is equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: To get the desired results I need to add where condition for subquery. JOIN (SELECT min(order_date) AS first_order_date FROM orders WHERE  id = 73) as fod ON 1 = 1